# The Range of Taxi Fares

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, optimization

You are in the back of a NYC taxi, and know exactly how fare your trip was in miles (m), and exactly how long it took in hours (t). The taxi driver gives you bill, but you want to make sure they've charged you correctly.

You know that taxi fares are calculated as follows:
"There is a $2.50 initial charge, plus 50 cents per 1/5 mile when traveling above 12mph or per 60 seconds in slow traffic or when the vehicle is stopped."

You know that your taxi never traveled above 60mph, but can't recall what proportion (p) of time was spent traveling above 12mph.

The question is, what is the minimum and maximum amount (in terms of t and m) that your fare should cost?

For example, if the trip was 10 miles in 1 hour, it could have been 50 mins stationary and 10 mins @ 60mph (This would be 2.5 + 0.5*50 + 2.5*10 = \$52.50). And this is not as simple as assuming p=0 and p=1 are the bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two important observations:

> At the boundary between fast and slow fare, i.e. at 12 mph, the slow rate is the same as the fast rate. At 12mph, or 1/5 mile per minute, \$0.50/minute is the same as \$2.50/mile.
>  Also, going slower or faster than 12mph costs more. Going slower you pay more per mile, and going faster you pay more per minute.

From that you can deduce minimum fare:

> On top of the initial \$2.50, you pay at least \$0.50 per minute, and also at least \$2.50 per mile. Therefore the minimum fare is:
>   $$2.50 + \max(0.50\cdot60 t,\ 2.50\cdot m )$$
>  In other words, if the average speed is less than 12mph you pay at least the minute rate (achieved if you never go above 12mph), and if the average speed is more than 12mph you pay at least the mile rate (achieved if you never go below 12mph).

For the maximum fare:

> The worst case is if you go 60mph the whole distance, and stand still the rest of the time. That way you take the most expensive rate in both parts of the fare regime, and spend the most time and travel the most miles at those expensive rates.
>  At 60mph or 1 mile per minute, you take $m$ minutes to traverse the distance. The remaining $60t-m$ minutes are spent standing still. This gives a maximum fare of:
>   $$2.50 + 0.50\cdot(60t-m) +2.50\cdot m = 2.50 + 0.50\cdot60 t +2.00\cdot m$$

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a really straight forward math problem, so I'm probably wrong, but:

> p can be anywhere from 0 (never above 12mph) to 1 (always above 12mph) therefore the bill can range anywhere from 2.5 + 30t to 2.5 + 2.5m

To optimize it further from here:

> Your average speed is m/t. The average must be below 60; if the average is under 12 then p will be closer to the 0 side of things, and the total bill should be closer to 2.5 + 30t. The higher the average speed, the closer p will be to 1 and the total bill will be to 2.5 + 2.5m

Comment: Great suggestion, but if we travel 10 miles in 1 hour, where 10 minutes were spent traveling at 60mph and 50 minutes were spent stationary, then your maths says that we could spend anywhere from \$32.5 to \$27.5 (which is reversed order for one), when really the fare was \$25 + \$25 = \$50

Comment: I can't seem to edit the above sorry, but it should be \$52.50 due to the initial charge.